# C# Regular Expression regex to match characters in last group, but not empty group

Tags: c#, regex, string, capture-group

Please can any one advise me of a solution that will allow my regular expression to match the following data lines...

```
0002,Area (Region Name),No value
0003,Area (Region Name),Up North
```

...but should fail on this line (due to the empty last group)

```
0001,Area (Region Name),
```

My current expression is:

```
(?<BRANCH_CODE>[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,8}),(?<UDA_NAME>[a-zA-Z0-9!"\£\$\%\^\&\*\(\)\-+_ /]{1,50}),(?<UDA_VALUE>[a-zA-Z0-9!"\£\$\%\^\&\*\(\)\-+_ /]{1,50})
```

... which works fine in Expresso, but **NOT** in my C# code!

Any help appreciated. Thank you.

Reference that has not helped:
[Regular expression matches an extra empty group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13892045/regular-expression-matches-an-extra-empty-group)

Comment: replace `"` with `""`

Comment: I cannot reproduce your result ([demo](http://ideone.com/brl4dJ)). Is there anything that you do differently from what's in the demo? I copied your regex and input strings.

Comment: Bang on @AvinashRaj. Do you want to post that as an answer so I can mark it as such?

Comment: so you don't want to match `0001,Area (Region Name),` ? If you want to match this line also, then use this https://regex101.com/r/rJ6vV1/5

Comment: @AvinashRaj - No I need to reject that line, as the last group is empty so should fail validation.

So your first answer worked a charm. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Escape all the double quotes .

```
@"(?<BRANCH_CODE>[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,8}),(?<UDA_NAME>[a-zA-Z0-9!""\£\$\%\^\&\*\(\)\-+_ /]{1,50}),(?<UDA_VALUE>[a-zA-Z0-9!""\£\$\%\^\&\*\(\)\-+_ /]{1,50})"
```

Answer (score 1):

The expression looks correct, but I would ensure you've got a start and end character on your expression, or it might match within a string.

```
^(?<BRANCH_CODE>[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,8}),(?<UDA_NAME>[a-zA-Z0-9!"\£\$\%\^\&\*\(\)\-+_ /]{1,50}),(?<UDA_VALUE>[a-zA-Z0-9!"\£\$\%\^\&\*\(\)\-+_ /]{1,50})$
```